# Splitting Binary files and adding data to each chunk?

Tags: java, file, binding, split

I have to work on a project in which I have to convert a binary file into a custom file format, which requires splitting the file adding some data to it and then repacking it into the new file.

For Example

I have a file of 1 MB and I have to split it into chunks of fixed length and then adding some data as a header to it.
After that the entire file will be repackaged into a new file.

Please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you use a [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) to read chunks of x bytes into individual byte arrays, where x is your chunk size. I would suggest to store these byte arrays in an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Then you create a [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) for creating the new file.

Finally, you iterate over your ArrayList with a for loop and write the contents of the arrays to the DataOutputStream, preceded or followed by the additional data you need to add for each chunk.

I hope I was able to help you. When something is unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: I used your suggestion and I am posting my code now there is some problem the file is not being created correctly.

Comment: Then you should open a new question with your code and an exact definition of "not being created correctly" (expected behavior vs. actual behavior).