# Breaking binary files

Tags: java, io, arraylist, arrays

With reference to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296295/splitting-binary-files-and-adding-data-to-each-chunk).

I have made the program with the following approach:
The program first reads 2k of data from the file and stores it into a byte array.
Then the data to be added to each packet is also stored in an array and both are added to an array list.
The array list is then written to an output stream for the file.

The Code is here:

```
File bin=chooser.getSelectedFile();
int filesize=(int)bin.length();
int pcount=filesize/2048; 
byte[] file=new byte[filesize];
byte[] meta=new byte[12];
int arraysize=pcount*12+filesize;
byte[] rootfile=new byte[46];
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
String root;
prbar.setVisible(true);
int mark=0;
String metas;
try{
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(bin);
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(bin.getName().replace(".bin", ".xyz"));
    ObjectOutputStream os=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    root="46kb"+"5678"+"0000"+pcount+"MYBOX"+"13"+"S208";
    rootfile=root.getBytes();
    for(int n=0;n<=pcount;n++)
    {
        fis.read(file, 0, 2048);
        mark=mark+2048;
        int v=(mark/filesize)*100;
        prbar.setValue(v);
        metas="02KB"+"1234"+n;
        meta=metas.getBytes();

        al.add(rootfile);
        al.add(meta);
        al.add(file);
    }
    os.writeObject(al.toArray());
}
catch(Exception ex){
    erlabel.setText(ex.getMessage());
}
```

The program runs without any errors but the file is not created correctly.
Either the approach is wrong or the code.

Please Help

Comment: What do you mean with "not created correctly"? What is the result and in what way does it differ from the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be writing your own binary format but you are using ObjectOutputStream which has it own header. writeObject write an Object not data in a manner that lets a Java process deserialize that object e.g. with it class hierarchy and field names.

For binary, I suggest you use a plain DataOutputStream with a BufferedOutputStream which will be more efficient and do what you want.

I also suggest you write the data as you generate it rather than using an ArrayList. This will use less memory, make the code simpler and be faster.

---

I would write the code more like this

```
File bin = chooser.getSelectedFile();
int filesize = (int) bin.length();
int pcount = (filesize + 2048 - 1) / 2048;
byte[] file = new byte[2048];

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(bin);
String name2 = bin.getName().replace(".bin", ".xyz");
OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name2));
byte[] rootfile = ("46kb" + "5678" + "0000" + pcount + "MYBOX" + "13" + "S208").getBytes("UTF-8");

for (int n = 0; n < pcount; n++) {
    os.write(rootfile);
    byte[] metas = ("02KB" + "1234" + n).getBytes("UTF-8");
    os.write(metas);

    int len = fis.read(file);

    os.write(file, 0, len);
    int percent = 100 * n / pcount;
    prbar.setValue(percent);
}
ow.close();
```

Comment: Just for the info...In this part of code
    fis.read(file, 0, 2048);
        mark=mark+2048;
        int v=(mark/filesize)*100;
        prbar.setValue(v);
        metas="02KB"+"1234"+n;
        meta=metas.getBytes();

        al.add(rootfile);
        al.add(meta);
        al.add(file);

the first thing added to the list would be the rootfile and then meta and then file right?? But when i see the file all the meta string are at the end of the file?
why??

Comment: Can you update your code in the question where you followed my instructions to remove ObjectOutputStream and ArrayList?

Comment: I am using an array list with apache commons serialization utils.

Comment: You need to ensure any library you use doesn't use ObjectOutputStream as well or you can't use it. It would explain why all the metas are at the end. This is because Java Serialization only sends each object once and since only the `meta` changes, only these will appear at the end.

Comment: I changed and removed quite a bit. This will be much more efficient as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16829/discussion-between-anirudhvarma-and-peter-lawrey)

Comment: it only adds meta once,i want that meta to be attached to every 2 kb chunk

Comment: It add the meta every time it goes around the loop. If it adds it once, then there was only one block.

Comment: i know..thats why i am confused

Comment: The most likely cause is that a) you are looking at an old file b) not running the code you think you are. I suggest you step through the code in a debugger to see what it is doing and why.

Comment: The solution works fine for me. You need to investigate why its not working because changing this code won't help.

Answer (score 1):

With the smallest thing first:

```
int v=(mark/filesize)*100;
```

Is using integer division yielding always 0 I think.

```
int v = mark * 100 / filesize;
```

The byte[] object (`file` for instance) is created once and many times added to the list.
You get n copies of the last overwrite.